# Notation of relations - dot

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> Relation is transitive if and only if $r\cdot r \subseteq r$.

I'm not sure how I should interpret it. What does the dot stand for?

Comment: Composition: $\langle x,y\rangle\in r\circ r$ if and only if there is a $z$ such that $\langle x,z\rangle,\langle z,y\rangle\in r$. (It really ought to be $\circ$ rather than $\cdot$.)

Comment: @teei: Let $X$ be your basis set with $R \subseteq X \times X$. Then, $r$ being *transitive* means $\forall x,y,z \in X: (x R y) \wedge (y R z) \supset (x R z)$.